# Running system rm -rf on an online compiler

Tags: bash, python, command-line-arguments

*I have not written the command using proper syntax in order to prevent any accidental misfire*
I recently read about the danger of using the command rm -rf in root directory but was wondering about a situation.
We have seen many online compilers which send the requests to the server and provide output after processing so I was thinking what if we pass this command as in order to simulate it in the root directory.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O9RCA.png)
Would this wipe out the server data?

*Sorry if I am bad at expressing doubts as you can see I am a noobie*

Comment: The online compilers usually run in a restricted or emulated environment like docker, chroot, virtual machine, etc. Moreover, the user running the compiler won't have permissions to write to the root directory. So, you can maybe break the machine running your compiler session, but that's the maximum damage you can cause.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, because you forgot `--no-preserve-root`, but that's just me nitpicking.

The actual answer is "we don't know". Each service will be set up differently. Some will probably be susceptible. These won't last long though. Either their admins will give up or learn on their mistakes.

Some will attempt system call filtering. That's something, but it's always just a matter of time until someone figures out how to bypass it.

Others, I imagine, will evaluate each snippet in a disposable, isolated environment, for example a Docker container. Destroying these is harmless for the service - the host will be untouched and the container would be deleted after use anyway.